# Вопросы по написанию форума

Tags: pdo, ajax, php, форум

В общем-то, встала задача в написании простого форума на сайт, функционал : распределение тем по разделам, соответственно, создание-удаление-редактирование тем и разделов, распределение пользовательских групп (пользователь, местный, модер, админ и тд).

Обработчик BB-Code, Ajax и тд уже имеется и используется в чате, да и прочие таки мелочи типо открыть \ закрыть тему, сделать раздел приватным и тд тоже не проблема.

Так вот, следующие вопросы, которые я хотел бы задать:

1. Как лучше хранить данные - в отдельной базе или же поместить всё в одну таблицу и разбирать по полям разделов и тд.
2. Как можно минимизировать количество запросов к БД (весь сайт использует PDO)
3. С чего стоит браться с самого начала вообще?
4. Где можно почитать более подробно о написании WYSIWYG редакторов?

Вопросов об интеграции какого либо готового движка вообще не стоит, ибо во первых хочется своего опыта набраться в этом деле, во вторых очень уж геморройно разгребать чужой код.

Помогите, товарищи, что посоветуете? На какой путь наставите?

Возможно, по ходу дела появятся еще несколько вопросов, но пока только это :)

Comment: не писать самому. хотите опыта - разгребайте чужой код, участвуйте в разработке, присылайте патчи.

Comment: @eicto , попытки разгрести были, и даже в принципе понятно всё, но переписывать треть движка ради интеграции к небольшому сайту желания мало.

Comment: @Виталий RS, может вы не тот движок смотрели ? в чем вообще проблема интеграции ? зачем вам писать wisywig если их тысячи. Откуда треть движка, что у вас за такие уникальные требования ?

Comment: @eicto смотрел форум IPB, ковырял форум из ICMS, phpbb.
Требования не уникальные, нужно даже меньше, чем есть в этих движках. 
Остальное, что смотрел запнулось на разработке лет 5 назад и требует конкретной доработки

Comment: https://community.nodebb.org/ https://github.com/NodeBB/NodeBB тут может быть интересно.

Comment: вставлю мнение за [discourse](http://www.discourse.org/)

Comment: вставлю мнение за [punbb][1]

[1]: http://punbb.ru/

Comment: @Etki, @thunder, это, конечно, всё замечательно, но их еще интегрировать нужно, что мегагеморройно

Comment: @Виталий RS говорит человек, собравшийся писать все с нуля

Comment: @Etki ну давайте разберемся, что выйдет в плане меньшего геморроя:
1. не придется разбирать тонны чужого кода, дабы прикрутить всё.
2. я буду точно знать, ЧТО и ГДЕ лежит и как работает. 
3. если вдруг нужно будет прикрутить что то еще - не нужно будет снова рыться и пытаться внять, почму тут так, а не эдак. и откуда тут это, и почему не то.

Comment: @Виталий RS b 4.й пункт забыли всю эту канетель придется поддерживать вам всю жизнь, баги будут не такие как у всех, а собственные, 

теперь по вашим пунктам

  1. чтобы интегрировать не нужно разбирать тонны чужого кода, я интегрировал вообще проприетарные вещи, посложнее форумов без доступа к коду. Изучение движка, с целью расширения/интеграции надо начинать не с чтения его исходников, а с чтения док-ции программного апи, и developers guide.
  2. Причем вы и только вы
  3. этот пукт справедлив так-же и для хорошо изученного апи движка который вы можете выбрать.

Comment: @Виталий RS, я, пожалуй, сбегаю за попкорном

Comment: @Виталий RS, когда закончите работу над "движком", не забудьте сразу выложить весь его код [сюда][1]


  [1]: http://govnokod.ru/

Comment: punbb! размахивая всяким!

(да один хрен будет угрёбищный клон пых-пых-бе-бе, о чем спич-то?)

Comment: оспади, ну возьмите [SMF][1], там отдельный файл изкаропки для интеграции есть... даже моих мозгов хватило, когда я только начинал разбираться с php :)

[1]: http://www.simplemachines.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Для каждого функционального блока (пользователи, темы, разделы) отдельная таблица.
2. Используйте кеширование (например для разделов форума, не думаю что они у вас так часто меняються).
3. С изучения паттернов (MVC например) т.к. они пригодяться для разработки архитектуры архи приложения. Хотя я бы вам не советовал писать все с нуля. Лучше всего для вас будки наверное использование фреймворка (Yii, Lara el - советую)
4. Тут уж точно лучше брать готовое решение. Вот например, для начала [Bootstrap-wysiwyg: крошечный текстовый редактор | Хабрахабр](http://habrahabr.ru/post/176897/)

Answer (score 1):

Первое правило - все уже написано за вас.

Серьезно, phpBB чем не устраивает?

PS опыта вы намного больше наберетесь разгребая чужой код, поверьте.